# Scrollable full height div using flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to create a layout as shown below.

[image]

The problem is the left menu. I want to use full height - I got that working. The problem is when there are too many items. Then I want to have an overflow scroll. So the full page should always fill the full screen, but the page should never be scrollable. Just the Left Menu part.

I have a CodePen going on [here](https://codepen.io/riha/pen/PoGdBYE). It work as I want it, until there are too many items in the menu and I can get overflow scrolling working in a good response way.

Uncomment the items = 40 line in the javascript window to see the issue.

```
items = 4 // looks ok
//items = 40 // too long
```

Is there a good technique to get this working?

Comment: Add `overflow: scroll` to `menu-items`

Comment: Isschh ... I feel so smart now ... Was sure I had tested that a 100 times already. Thanks ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you're missing is `overflow: auto;` on your `.menu-items` class.